# Could not push code to the CodeCommit repository

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit

I am trying to push my code to the beanstalk but I am getting an error when I hit the `eb create` command

```
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Starting environment deployment via CodeCommit
Could not push code to the CodeCommit repository:
ERROR: CommandError - An error occurred while handling git command.
Error code: 128 Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/origin/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have already created an environment using aws beanstalk, how I should push to that.

Comment: `git` is unable to push to `https://git-codecommit.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/origin/`. To rectify this, you can perform `eb codesource` to reassociate your local branch with the correct remote CodeCommit repository. You can also manually rectify the URL in the `.git/config` file of your project.

Comment: I want to push to both places github and codecommit @progfan

Comment: Are your IAM permissions configured correctly to allow code commit access?

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to your AccessKey and SecurityKey. Perhaps AK or SK has expired/inactivaded.
In my case with the same error, the problem was an expired key.
After releasing a new key, make sure the git credential store have the new key (if used).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by:

- Attaching `AWSCodeCommitPowerUser` to my user group
- Generating a CodeCommit credential for my user.

**STEP 1**

Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.

In the IAM console, in the navigation pane, choose Users, and then choose the IAM user you want to configure for CodeCommit access.

On the Permissions tab, choose Add Permissions.

In Grant permissions, choose Attach existing policies directly.

From the list of policies, select AWSCodeCommitPowerUser or another managed policy for CodeCommit access. For more information, see AWS managed (predefined) policies for CodeCommit.

**STEP 2**

On the user details page, choose the Security Credentials tab, and in HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit, choose Generate.

Use the `Username` and `Password` when prompt to enter credentials for the git repo

Take a look at this article for more information https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-gc.html